# Button to Refresh GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, stored-procedures, gridview

Basically, I have a SQLDataSource that is a stored procedure that has two parameters (datetime). I have two calendars that set these parameters on click. I have checked the stored procedure and the parameters work, but the GridView is not showing the results of the stored procedure because the user has to click on the calendar to set parameters for a result. I think the GridView is just showing the stored procedure results without any parameters (so it's blank). This is my suspicion because I also have an "Export to Excel" button that exports the GridView to Excel and the Excel file is also blank after being downloaded.

I think I need to implement a button that refreshes the GridView so that the user can select the date parameters with the two calendars for the stored procedure which creates a result. The button would then refresh/update the GridView that only shows the initial blank result with the new stored procedure result. How do I create this "refresh button"?

For reference,
aspx.cs looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DateTime fromDate = new DateTime();
        DateTime toDate = new DateTime();


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
            GridView1.AllowSorting = false;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=gvtoexcel.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();

            GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
            GridView1.AllowSorting = true;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
        }

        protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fromDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = fromDate.ToString();


        }

        protected void Calendar2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toDate = Calendar2.SelectedDate;
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters[1].DefaultValue = toDate.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

And the .aspx looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .style2
        {
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="style1" style="margin-left: 40px">

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BIZ_DBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="Payrolldeduction" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime" Name="fromDate" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime" Name="toDate" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <div class="style1">

        Payroll Report<br />
        </div>
        <div class="style2">
            <br />
            From:</div>
        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" 
            onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged" style="text-align: left">
        </asp:Calendar>
        <div class="style2">
            To:</div>
        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" style="text-align: left">
        </asp:Calendar>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" 
            Text="Export to Excel" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            onselectedindexchanged="Page_Load" AllowPaging="True">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="INST_ID" HeaderText="INST_ID" 
                    SortExpression="INST_ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EMPLOYEE_ID" HeaderText="EMPLOYEE_ID" 
                    SortExpression="EMPLOYEE_ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HR_DEDUCTION_AND_BENEFITS_CODE" 
                    HeaderText="HR_DEDUCTION_AND_BENEFITS_CODE" 
                    SortExpression="HR_DEDUCTION_AND_BENEFITS_CODE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Column1" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Column1" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="WITHHOLDING_LIABILITY_ACCOUNT_MASK" 
                    HeaderText="WITHHOLDING_LIABILITY_ACCOUNT_MASK" 
                    SortExpression="WITHHOLDING_LIABILITY_ACCOUNT_MASK" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HR_DEDUCTION_AND_BENEFITS_ID" 
                    HeaderText="HR_DEDUCTION_AND_BENEFITS_ID" 
                    SortExpression="HR_DEDUCTION_AND_BENEFITS_ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CHECK_DATE" HeaderText="CHECK_DATE" 
                    SortExpression="CHECK_DATE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CHECK_NO" HeaderText="CHECK_NO" 
                    SortExpression="CHECK_NO" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FIN_INST_ACCT_ID" HeaderText="FIN_INST_ACCT_ID" 
                    SortExpression="FIN_INST_ACCT_ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Column2" HeaderText="Column2" ReadOnly="True" 
                    SortExpression="Column2" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HR_DEDUCTION_AND_BENEFIT_CYCLE_CODE" 
                    HeaderText="HR_DEDUCTION_AND_BENEFIT_CYCLE_CODE" 
                    SortExpression="HR_DEDUCTION_AND_BENEFIT_CYCLE_CODE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LENGTH" HeaderText="LENGTH" 
                    SortExpression="LENGTH" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EMPLOYEE_COMPUTED_AMOUNT" 
                    HeaderText="EMPLOYEE_COMPUTED_AMOUNT" 
                    SortExpression="EMPLOYEE_COMPUTED_AMOUNT" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EMPLOYEE_BANK_ROUTING_NUMBER" 
                    HeaderText="EMPLOYEE_BANK_ROUTING_NUMBER" 
                    SortExpression="EMPLOYEE_BANK_ROUTING_NUMBER" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT_TYPE" 
                    HeaderText="EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT_TYPE" SortExpression="EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT_TYPE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER" 
                    HeaderText="EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER" SortExpression="EMPLOYEE_ACCOUNT_NUMBER" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EMPLOYER_COMPUTED_AMOUNT" 
                    HeaderText="EMPLOYER_COMPUTED_AMOUNT" 
                    SortExpression="EMPLOYER_COMPUTED_AMOUNT" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EMPLOYEE_GROSS_AMOUNT" 
                    HeaderText="EMPLOYEE_GROSS_AMOUNT" SortExpression="EMPLOYEE_GROSS_AMOUNT" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="EMPLOYER_GROSS_AMOUNT" 
                    HeaderText="EMPLOYER_GROSS_AMOUNT" SortExpression="EMPLOYER_GROSS_AMOUNT" />
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="PAYROLL_EXCLUDE" HeaderText="PAYROLL_EXCLUDE" 
                    SortExpression="PAYROLL_EXCLUDE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VOID_DATE" HeaderText="VOID_DATE" 
                    SortExpression="VOID_DATE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BATCH_QUEUE_ID" HeaderText="BATCH_QUEUE_ID" 
                    SortExpression="BATCH_QUEUE_ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BATCH_CODE" HeaderText="BATCH_CODE" 
                    SortExpression="BATCH_CODE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FY" HeaderText="FY" SortExpression="FY" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="END_DATE" HeaderText="END_DATE" 
                    SortExpression="END_DATE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="COMMENTS" HeaderText="COMMENTS" 
                    SortExpression="COMMENTS" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BATCH_CRITERIA_USED" 
                    HeaderText="BATCH_CRITERIA_USED" SortExpression="BATCH_CRITERIA_USED" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="COLUMN_VALUE" HeaderText="COLUMN_VALUE" 
                    SortExpression="COLUMN_VALUE" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="REPLACEMENT" HeaderText="REPLACEMENT" 
                    SortExpression="REPLACEMENT" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LAST_NAME" HeaderText="LAST_NAME" 
                    SortExpression="LAST_NAME" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FIRST_NAME" HeaderText="FIRST_NAME" 
                    SortExpression="FIRST_NAME" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MIDDLE_NAME" HeaderText="MIDDLE_NAME" 
                    SortExpression="MIDDLE_NAME" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

**Update:**

I somehow managed to make the dates from calendar selection stay put and act as parameters (the user now selects the calendar dates and then the confirm button / button2 which was previously the Export to Excel button which is now button3), but the GridView is not showing the stored procedure's results even with the parameters set. No errors are popping up either. What is going on?

Here's how the code looks now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DateTime fmDate = new DateTime();
        DateTime toDate = new DateTime();


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlDataSource SqlDataSource1 = new SqlDataSource();
            SqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource1";
            this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1);
            SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BIZ_DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Payrolldeduction";
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear();

            FormParameter fmDate = new FormParameter("@Param1", Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString());
            FormParameter toDate = new FormParameter("@Param2", Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString());
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(fmDate);
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(toDate);

            GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
            GridView1.AllowSorting = false;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=newexcelreport.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());

            GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
            GridView1.AllowSorting = false;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fmDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate;
            fromDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = fmDate.ToString();

        }

        protected void Calendar2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            toDate = Calendar2.SelectedDate;
            SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters[1].DefaultValue = toDate.ToString();
        }

        }
    }
```

aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .style2
        {
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="style1" style="margin-left: 40px">

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:BIZ_DBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="Payrolldeduction" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime" Name="fromDate" />
                <asp:Parameter DbType="DateTime" Name="toDate" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <div class="style1">

        Payroll Report<br />
        </div>
        <div class="style2">
            <br />
            From:</div>

            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fromDate" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"  style="text-align: left"> </asp:Calendar>
        <div class="style2">
            To:</div>
        <asp:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" style="text-align: left">
        </asp:Calendar>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" Text="Confirm" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" onclick="Button3_Click" Text="Export" />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You NEVER call Page_Load as a GridView event handler.  Beside the fact that, based on your code, it's doing nothing anyway, it **is** called every time your page posts back regardless of the button that caused the post back.
2. Your `SqlDataSource` select parameters should be `Control Parameters` that reference the 2 calendar controls.  This means you do not need to handle the calendar's SelectionChanged events, it will be automatic. BUT...
3. Calendar Controls auto postback anyway, which means you need to validate the dates either by asp valdiation or in your stored procedure and only return a DataSet if the dates have any meaning.
4. As for your GridView - it will always try to refresh because you do this: `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"`. In any asp databound control, when you set the `DataSourceID` property, your control will ALWAYS make a call to DataBind() on every postback.

---

**Update 2015-03-02 ~1850EST**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // validate the dates here then:

    // If you MUST use Parameters over ControlParameters, 
    // then you need to assign the date here like this:
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("fromDate").DefaultValue = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString()
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("toDate").DefaultValue = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString()

    // No need to force databind because in the markup you set the property
    //     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    // This will force the Gridview to call DataBind() on each 
    // postback.  And Control changed events (button click in this case) 
    // occur before DataBind() events

    //###############################################################
    //###############################################################

    //None of this stuff is needed. It's already done in the markup:

    //###############################################################
    SqlDataSource SqlDataSource1 = new SqlDataSource();
    SqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource1";
    this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1);
    SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BIZ_DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "Payrolldeduction";
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Clear();

    FormParameter fmDate = new FormParameter("@Param1", Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString());
    FormParameter toDate = new FormParameter("@Param2", Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString());
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(fmDate);
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(toDate);

    GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    //###############################################################
    //###############################################################
}
```

Comment: Please look at the Update of first post. Could you assist me further? Thanks.